# Fibonacci sequence numbers to list with an optional start parameter

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which will take a number n as its parameter and returns the first n elements of a fibonacci sequence in a list.

But, I also want to include an optimal parameter 'start' (a pair of numbers, which specifies the first two elements of a generalised Fibonacci sequence.

Any ideas how to include the optional parameter in the code?

Thanks for help in an advance.

```
def fibonacci(n: int, start: tuple[int, int] = (0, 1)) -> list[int]:
    sequence = [0,1]

    for i in range(3,n+1):
        next_num = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]
        sequence.append(next_num)
    
    return sequence

print(fibonacci(8))
```

Current output
`[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]`

---

Desired input `fibonacci(6, start=(2, 2))`

Desired output  `[2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16]`

Curent output `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because You pass `start` as a `tuple` you need to convert this to a `list` and assign it to `sequence`.

```
def fibonacci(n, start = (0, 1)):
    sequence = list(start)

    for i in range(3,n+1):
        next_num = sequence[-1] + sequence[-2]
        sequence.append(next_num)
    
    return sequence

print(fibonacci(8))
# [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13]

print(fibonacci(6, start=(2, 2)))
# [2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16]
```

Answer (score 0):

You might find that implementing this as a generator is more flexible. Something like this:

```
def fibonacci(n=float('inf'), *, start=(0,1)):
    a, b = start
    while n > 0:
        yield a
        a, b = b, a + b
        n -= 1

print(*fibonacci(6, start=(2,2)), sep=', ')
print(*fibonacci(6), sep=', ')
for f in fibonacci():
    print(f)
    if f > 10:
        break
```

**Output:**

```
2, 2, 4, 6, 10, 16
0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5
0
1
1
2
3
5
8
13
```